# Como puedo repetir una funcion Java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing, bucles

Buenas quiero repetir mi funcion que me genera una posicion aleatoria en el frame y me mueve un label de lugar. Pero me ejecuta la funcion 1 sola vez. Alguien tiene una solucion?. Dejo el codigo, mi idea es que al apretar un -boton se ejecute la funcion traer que me repite 100 veces la funcion generar.

```
public void generar(){
            int x=(int)(Math.random()*300);
            int y=(int)(Math.random()*300);
            lbl1.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public void traer(){


        for(int i=0; i<100;i++){
            generar();

        }


    }
```

Comment: Lo más probable es que la función se ejecute las 300 veces que indicas en el código, pero lo haga tan rápidamente que ni lo veas. Puedes poner un log o un `System.out.println` en el código (con las coordenadas) para comprobarlo.

Comment: Además, si ejecutas esta lógica dentro del *thread* de control de *Swing* (que se encarga de procesar eventos y redibujar la GUI), mientras estés haciendo todos estos cálculos no se redibujará la pantalla (se quedaría "bloqueada" y solo saldrían los datos de la última posición). Tendrías que hacerlo desde un *thread* independiente.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte del tiempo, le puse un timer que demorara un poco el proceso y con una variable estatica controlo cuantas veces se ejecuta la funcion. Gracias por tu aporte!

Comment: Igual podrías investigar un poco sobre la clase `SwingUtilities`, seguramente te sorprenderá lo mucho que se aprende acerca de hilos en la interfaz gráfica.